# How does inplace=False not give a keyerror in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

so I had a small doubt. I was trying to drop 3 columns when I was rendering the final output of my interactive dropdown which filters the data frame. Note that this dropdown uses those 2 of those 3 dropped columns (Year, Month) for filtering. Hence I wrote `df_filter = df_reviews` which would bring those 3 columns back (needed for filtering) if the function is called again when the interact is used for the second time. However, when I use `inplace = True` it gives me a

> 

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Year'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\interaction.py in update(self, *args)
    254                     value = widget.get_interact_value()
    255                     self.kwargs[widget._kwarg] = value
--> 256                 self.result = self.f(**self.kwargs)
    257                 show_inline_matplotlib_plots()
    258                 if self.auto_display and self.result is not None:

<ipython-input-88-405b00facead> in filter_dataframe(Year, Month)
     10 
     11         else:
---> 12             df_filter = df_reviews.loc[df_reviews['Year'] == Year]
     13 
     14         if(Month=='All'):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Year
```

even though i am doing `df_filter = df_reviews.` (which brings back the dropped columns)

The code:

```
def test(Year, Month):
        
        global df_dropdown
        global time_list
        #df_filter = None
        df_filter=df_reviews
        
        if(Year=='All'):
            pass
        
        else:
            df_filter = df_reviews.loc[df_reviews['Year'] == Year]
            
        if(Month=='All'):
            pass  
        
        else:
            df_filter = df_filter.loc[df_filter['Month'] == Month]
            
        df_filter.drop(['Year'], axis = 1, inplace=True)
        df_filter.drop(['Month'], axis = 1, inplace=True)
        df_filter.drop(['Day'], axis = 1, inplace=True)
        
        df_dropdown =  df_filter
        time_list = [Month, Year]
        display(df_filter)
        return time_list

interact(test, Year=['All','2018', '2019', '2020'], Month=['All','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
                  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'])
```

However when i changed it to this it worked:

```
df_filter = df_filter.drop(['Year'], axis = 1, inplace=False)
df_filter = df_filter.drop(['Month'], axis = 1, inplace=False)
df_filter = df_filter.drop(['Day'], axis = 1, inplace=False)
```

Can someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full error you are getting, from which line of code.

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo done

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you do

`df_filter=df_reviews`

It creates a reference to the df_reviews dataframe which means when you drop a column, it drops the column from the original df_reviews dataframe.

Try printing df_reviews after you do the inplace drop on df_filter, you will notice the columns will not be present.

`df_filter = df_filter.drop(['Year'], axis = 1, inplace=False)`

df.drop returns a dataframe which is then being assigned to df_filter thereby creating a separate copy of the data and not modifying df_reviews.